# EF Linq Query Collection with an eager loaded child-collection

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, ef4-code-only

I'm using EF4.1 code first,

I'm trying to to create a query which returns a collection with an eager loaded child-collection.
Both has to be ordered by **Position**  and **IsActive == true**

These Classes are mapped.

```
public class Type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    .......
    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    .......
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

DTOs:

```
    public class TypeDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<CategoryDTO> Categories { get; set; }
    }

public class CategoryDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }

        public virtual TypeDTO Type { get; set; }
    }
```

What I have got:

With DTO:

```
var result = _db.Types
                             .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                             .Where(x => x.AreaId== areaId)
                             .Select(x => new TypeDTO()
                             {
                                 Name = x.Name,
                                 UniqueName = x.UniqueName,
                                 Categories = x.Categories.Where(c => c.IsActive == true)
                                                          .OrderBy(c => c.Position)
                                                          .Select(c => new CategoryDTO()
                                                          {
                                                              Name = c.Name,
                                                              UniqueName = c.UniqueName
                                                          })
                                                          .ToList()

                             })
                             .ToList();
```

This throws :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...CategoryDTO]
>   ToList[...CategoryDTO](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[...CategoryDTO])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Without DTO:

```
var result2 = _db.Categories
                           .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                           .OrderBy(x => x.Position)
                           .Select(x => x.Type)
                           .Distinct()
                           .Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.AreaId== areaId)
                           .OrderBy(x => x.Position)
                           .ToList();
```

It runs without Error, but does not gives the right result, and does not ordering the child-collection

Other unsuccessful  approach :

```
var result = _db.Types
                           .Where(t => t.IsActive == true)
                           .Where(t => t.SiteId == siteId)
                           .Include(t => t.Categories
                                              .Where(c=>c.IsActive == true)
                                              .OrderBy(c=>c.Position))
                           .OrderBy(t => t.Position)
                           .ToList();
```

What am i missing?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
The final Solution:

```
public class TypeDTO
    {
        public Type Type { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }

var result = _db.Types
                .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                .Where(x => x.AreaId== areaId)
                .OrderBy(x=>x.Position)
                .Select(x => new TypeDTO()
                {
                   Type = x,
                   Categories =  x.Categories.Where(c => c.IsActive == true).OrderBy(c => c.Position)
                })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach..

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
     var activeTypes = context.Types.Where(t => t.IsActive)
                             .Select(t => new 
                             {
                                 Type= t,
                                 ActiveCategories = t.Categories.Where(c => c.IsActive)
                                                                .OrderBy(c => c.Position)
                             }).ToList();


}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but **types** has to be a list not an entry

Comment: Thanks, the edited version works. I needed to update the DTO class:**public class TypeDTO
    {
        public Type Type { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }**